# PHP way to force / set parameter to the URL

Tags: php

When I go to the following page in the CMS system:

> /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

It loads a table list which already has sorting etc... and by default it sorts by customer but I ideally can't modify the core controller file for this as would lose changes if / when system updates, so I'd prefer to use pre / post on controllers via addons.

cart.pre.php

```
if ($mode == 'cart_list') {

    if (empty($_REQUEST['sort_by'])) {
        $_REQUEST['sort_by'] = 'date';
    }

}
```

This is what I'm attempting but rather new to PHP so not sure, does not work anyway. If I apply directly to the URL &sort_by=date it will sort by date so somehow need to force it to sort this way.

Comment: Not working why? How you use it? Where? Can you show the code that fails? (Also please add the updated code editing your question ('edit' above) and delete yr answer)

Answer (score 0):

Ok worked out the solution, it needed to also have sort_order set so this worked for me:

```
if ($mode == 'cart_list') {

    if (empty($_REQUEST['sort_by'])) {
        $_REQUEST['sort_by'] = 'date';
        $_REQUEST['sort_order'] = 'desc';
    }

}
```